# Can not call model method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a class in Django model.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.numbers

    def checksum(self):
        #calculate checksum here
```

and in other function, I can call something like: ticket.checksum

But later, I add another method (get_scan)

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.numbers

    def checksum(self):
        #calculate checksum here

    def get_scan(self):
        #calculate get_scan here
```

but now I can not call ticket.get_scan (eventhough ticket.checksum still works)

I have tried different way like restart web server, calling in Django shell ... but it does not work.

Error:
'Ticket' object has no attribute 'get_scan'

Updated: it's about indentation problem

Comment: Post the actual code (perhaps it is wonky)?

Comment: Bit sill,but did you checked that you have proper indentation?

Comment: The actual stacktrace and error would be really helpful. Without it we can speculate a lot of things that could go wrong. Indentation, parenthesis, quoting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting any left over *.pyc files and restarting webserver

Comment: This is highly suspicious. I'd spend a few minutes looking at your import statements to make certain your referencing the models.py code you intend. If you are feeling really frustrated, change the name of Tickt to Ticket2.  Remember todo a "manage.py syncdb" afterwards. Renaming is a temporary change to make sure your import statements are working as u expect.